# Blackberry xml settings from resources to data folders

Tags: xml, eclipse, blackberry, default

For BB I need to know how, thinking about android or iOS,  I can copy the xml file of app "default settings" system from resources to "standard settings" into this folder for I can modify after this file. I would like to know which name has this folders too.

Thanks you! ;)

Answer (score 3):

There is no such predefined thing like xml-settings file for BlackBerry application. All application resources are encapsulated into *.cod file and cannot be edited when application is compiled. Consider having an external (located in blackberry filesystem) xml-file to store settings of your application.

When your application starts it checks for presence of settings.xml file (you can give an arbitrary name to the settings file).

If settings.xml exists, then your app reads its content, parses it and uses settings from this file.

If this file is not present, then application creates this file with hard-coded (into the application logic) default values.